# Difference between Message queue and OWIN

Tags: .net, queue, message-queue

I recently started learning about Message Queue in .NET.  I am confused that is what is the difference between OWIN Katana middle ware and Message Queue (MSMQ/ZeroMQ)??

Answer (score 1):

**Middleware** is just a layer in [Katana project](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana) architecture which is located between Application and Server. And **[MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** is a message queue implementation which can be used as a means to implement a communication between different components. So, MSMQ can be one of the implementations of Middleware.